# How to make this AngularJs Gallery Work ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am currently in the process of building up my knowledge in AngularJS. However I am having some issues running some code in Plunker.

Can some-one have a look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong? I have also included the code here.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('AlbumCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    {category : 'High', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400', description : 'Random Photo', stars : '4/5'},
    {category : 'Medium', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/sports', description : 'Sports Photo', stars : '3/5'},
    {category : 'Medium', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/animals', description : 'Animal Photo', stars : '3/5'},
    {category : 'High', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/abstract', description : 'Abstract Photo', stars : '5/5'},
    {category : 'Low', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/business', description : 'Business Photo', stars : '1/5'},
    {category : 'High', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/cats', description : 'Cat Photo', stars : '4/5'},
    {category : 'Medium', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/city', description : 'City Photo', stars : '3/5'},
    {category : 'Low', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/fashion', description : 'Fashion Photo', stars : '2/5'},
    {category : 'High', image : 'http://lorempixel.com/g/850/400/nature', description : 'Nature Photo', stars : '5/5'}
  ];
  
  $scope.currentImage = _.first($scope.images);
  
  $scope.imageCategories = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.images, 'category'));
    
  $scope.setCurrentImage = function(image) {
    $scope.currentImage = image;
  };
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 3.2rem; }

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  float: left;
  padding-left: .8rem;
}

.albumImage img { margin-bottom: .4rem; }

.angLogo {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  padding-top: 1.9rem;
}

.badge .glyphicon { padding-right: .4rem; }

label, select {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.wrapper {
    list-style: none;
    height: 480px;
    margin-left: 5.6rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
  }
  
  .hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #444;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      border-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .active {
      opacity: .74;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px #666;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
        <img src="//www.nganimate.org/img/angular-logo.png" alt="AngularJS Logo" class="angLogo"/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="albumImage">
                <img ng-src="{{currentImage.image}}" alt="{{currentImage.description}}"/>
              </div>
              <h3>{{currentImage.description}}</h3>
              <p class="badge"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>{{currentImage.stars}}</p>
              <select ng-model="categories"
                      ng-options="category for category in imageCategories">
                <option value="">All</option>
              </select>
              <label for="select">Select a Rating:</label>
            </div><!-- End of Column -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="list">
                  <li ng-repeat="image in images | filter:categories" ng-click="setCurrentImage(image)">
                    <img ng-src="{{image.image}}" alt="{{image.description}}"/>
                  </li>
                </ul><!-- End of List -->
              </div><!-- End of Wrapper -->
            </div><!-- End of Column -->
          </div><!-- End of Row -->
        </div><!-- End of Album Controller -->
      </div><!-- End of Column -->
    </div><!-- End of Row -->
  </div><!-- End of Container -->
</body><!-- End of Body -->
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6KcKvxHR9mZitFL6eidX?p=preview

Once I have the code running I would also like to amend so that there is an arrow selector to scroll through images and it changes the main image. And also I would like to add a zoom icon to the main image and it moves to fullscreen - I will create a separate question if required.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you using underscore js functions but you haven't included the library, so once you include the library the code will work. You can add this line inside head tag.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>`

Based on what you wanted i have created a fiddle.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OmYPG94kw5lOmDf6X1h4?p=preview

CSS was written using SCSS preprocessor in the link you shared,  but I am not sure if plunkr supports SCSS, so i converted it to plain css and now everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That appears to have got the pictures working however its not fully functional yet. Im using this codepen : http://codepen.io/joshadamous/pen/CJmIB does that help solve it any ?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by not fully functional yet? Based on  your question do you also want carousel and zoom feature?

Comment: If you check in the link you will see how the codepen looks. I am looking for it to be set up the same as this. If you check the above Plunker site you will see it is not set up the same way sadly.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope this answers your question